# Non-sendable type '[String : Any]?' exiting main actor-isolated context in call to non-isolated instance method XXX cannot cross actor boundary

Tags: ios, swift

I have a function that looks like this:

```
public final class MyClass {
  static let shared = MyClass()

  public func doSomething(dictionary: [String: Any]? = nil) async -> UIViewController {
    return await UIViewController()
  }
}
```

I call it like this inside a `UIViewController`:

```
final class MyViewController: UIViewController {
  @IBAction private func tapButton() {
    Task {
      let vc = await MyClass.shared.doSomething()
    }
  }
}
```

But it gives me a warning:

> Non-sendable type '[String : Any]?' exiting main actor-isolated context in call to non-isolated instance method 'doSomething(dictionary:)' cannot cross actor boundary

Note that you must have `Strict Concurrency Checking` in your Build Settings set to `Complete` or `Targeted` for this to show up in Xcode.

I know that functions inside a `UIViewController` are isolated to the MainActor and I want `tapButton()` to be. But what can I do about this to avoid this warning?

Comment: @Sweeper I've just updated, it reproduces with the code given for me

Comment: @Sweeper Ah I didn't realise it only showed when that's enabled. Updated question

Comment: You could replace `Any` with `Sendable` as the value type in the dictionary parameter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The dictionary is said to "exit main actor-isolated context" and "cross actor boundary" because `MyViewController` is a `@MainActor` class, but `MyClass` isn't. Whatever will be running `doSomething` is not the main actor, but the cooperative thread pool.

It is not safe for a non-`Sendable` type like `[String: Any]?` to cross actor boundaries. `[String: Any]?` is not `Sendable` because `Any` is not `Sendable`. Yes, you are only passing `nil` here, which should be safe, but Swift looks at the types only.

There are a few ways to solve this. Here are some that I thought of:

- take a `[String: any Sendable]?` instead
- annotate `MyClass` or `doSomething` with `@MainActor`
- use `Task.detached` instead of `Task.init`, so that the cooperative thread pool runs the task too. `Task.init` will inherit the current actor context, and at `tapButton`, it is the main actor.

Comment: Question: What version of Swift is `any Sendable` compatible with? 5.5+?

Comment: @Tometoyou I'm not sure, but the [SE proposal](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0302-concurrent-value-and-concurrent-closures.md) for `Sendable` says "Implemented (Swift 5.7)", so I don't think it is available in Swift 5.5 or 5.6.

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass `[String: Any]` across concurrency boundaries under "targeted" concurrency warnings, since it's not (and can't be) Sendable. Even though it's a default parameter, it's still being created in the calling context and then passed to the receiving context. To avoid that, you need to create the default parameter in the receiving context. Default parameters are just shortcuts for explicit overloads, so you can write the overload explicitly instead:

```
// Remove the default parameter here
public func doSomething(dictionary: [String: Any]?) async -> UIViewController {
    return await UIViewController()
}

// And define it explicitly as an overload
public func doSomething() async -> UIViewController {
    return await doSomething(dictionary: nil)
}
```

With this, the call to `doSomething()` doesn't create a Sendable problem.

That said, I expect that MyClass should actually be `@MainActor` (or at least `doSomething`). Creating a UIViewController on a non-main queue is legal if I remember correctly (though it might not be), but no method is legal to call on it outside the main queue.